# Create a mysql database login interface with Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, mysql-python

I'm learning how to code, and I was attempting to create a pyqt5 login interface where potential user can input host, user, password and daabase and log into mysql database
Simple enough, except that I'm a total newbie who wanna shift career to coding, so I don't seem to be able to grab the input into my .connect() no matter how hard  tried.
I've been attempting for 3 futile days now so if someone can help me I'll be grateful
That's my code

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import MySQLdb as mdb


class App(QWidget):


def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.title = 'Login'
    self.top = 100
    self.left = 100
    self.width = 400
    self.height = 400
    self.Log()



def Log(self):
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.height, self.width)

    self.host = QLineEdit(self)
    self.host.setPlaceholderText('Host')
    self.host.move(100, 100)
    self.user = QLineEdit(self)
    self.user.setPlaceholderText('User Name')
    self.user.move(100, 150)
    self.pw = QLineEdit(self)
    self.pw.setPlaceholderText('Password')
    self.pw.move(100, 200)
    self.db = QLineEdit(self)
    self.db.setPlaceholderText('Database')
    self.db.move(100, 250)

    btn = QPushButton('Click to login', self)
    btn.move(100, 300)
    btn.clicked.connect(self.SQL)

    self.show()

def SQL(self):
    try:
       conn = mdb.connect(suppsed to tak input from above here)
       QMessageBox.about(self, 'Connection', 'Done')
    except:
        QMessageBox.about(self, 'Connection', 'Failed')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Qt, it's really useful to get used to parse the C++ documentation. The page for [QLineEdit is here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html).

You can get input strings from a QLineEdit widget with the following code:

```
# Gets username and password from your widgets
input_user = self.user.text()
input_password = self.pw.text()
```

By the way, since you're new to coding, you should avoid doing this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
```

It will pollute the namespace and may create hard to track bugs. Also, the convention for function/method names in python is `snake_case`.

Comment: Nilo K. 
Thanks a million time, I owe you one.

I added those lines under the def connectDB(self): and now I can allow a user to use his own log to sign in.

I probably don't even understand what you're talking about. Like I said I'm learing. But I appreciate any direction to anywhere to read more in, so now I'll go read more about every piece you mentioned in your reply

Comment: You're welcome! My suggestion is to read a whole python book and then things will start to make sense :)

Comment: I definitely will. Today is the mark of my first month in coding, so I haven't knew much for sure. I was just trying to do a practical study side by side with theoretical reading, so I can see practically how it will behave. Thanks for stopping by to help, I won't waste anymore of your time for now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import MySQLdb as mdb


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Login'
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 400
        self.Log()



    def Log(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.height, self.width)

        self.host = QLineEdit(self)
        self.host.setPlaceholderText('Host')
        self.host.move(100, 100)
        self.user = QLineEdit(self)
        self.user.setPlaceholderText('User Name')
        self.user.move(100, 150)
        self.pw = QLineEdit(self)
        self.pw.setPlaceholderText('Password')
        self.pw.move(100, 200)
        self.db = QLineEdit(self)
        self.db.setPlaceholderText('Database')
        self.db.move(100, 250)

        btn = QPushButton('Click to login', self)
        btn.move(100, 300)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.SQL)

        self.show()

    def SQL(self):
        try:
            #conn = mdb.connect(suppsed to tak input from above here)
            # !!! indicate your names                 vvvv           vvvvvv      vvvvvv
            conn = mdb.connect(host="localhost",user="user", passwd="passwd",db="testdb")
            with conn:
                cur = conn.cursor()
                """
                cur.execute('''INSERT INTO pyqt5data(host, user, pw, ...)
                               VALUES (%s, %s, %s)''', 
                               ( self.host.text(),
                                 self.user.text(),
                                 self.pw.text() 
                                 ...
                               )
                           )
                """
                cur.close() 

            QMessageBox.about(self, 'Connection', 
                                    'Done \nconn-{} \ncur- {}'.format(conn, cur))


        except:
            QMessageBox.about(self, 'Connection', 'Failed')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: First I appreciate that you stopped to help.
Second I found a solution from the guy up. I wanted to use a 'dynamic' log screen where several users with several accounts can log in with their individual user and pass, which was fixed by allowing the SQL() to grab the input from the QlineEdit by the host.text()
So it works now finally and I can move to next thing.
I haven't slept well for three days because of that actually